# No button appearing on Nexus 7 compile

Tags: android, button

I am compiling and running to a Nexus 7 device and not the emulator because the emulator runs very slowly on my macbook.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

   <Button 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/button_send"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am following along with a book and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  I am using the ADT eclipse ide.  Any ideas? The text is there but the button doesn't show up, when I add a button in the graphical view it seems to work when it injects the code.

Comment: FYI, emulator or not, you can always preview the layouts in Eclipse. with the layout file open, just click the bottom-tab for "Graphical Layout."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextView fills parent. So there it no space left for a button. 
Change:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 2):

LinearLayout measures how much size is needed for each of its children one by one when using fill_parent. Therefore, in your example it sees that first child wants to have all available height (fill_parent) it gives it to it.

### If you don't care about spacing

Change `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

### Assuming you want your button at the bottom

You can fix this by using layout_weight. Tell both views to only use the space they need (ie, use wrap_content). Next set the first view to use layout_weight=1, so that the first view gets precedence when deciding which view gets the leftover space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hello" />

   <Button 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="0"
       android:text="Send"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what the result will look like, which is what I assume you want:

[image]

Comment: I am a bit unclear why the button is now going to the bottem of the screen.  If it is only taking the space that it needs.

Comment: wrap_content means a view will only use the space it needs. The extra space will go after the last item. However, by setting layout_weights you can determine where the space that would have been at the bottom goes (ie, determine where to place the space not needed by the size of the button and text).